# Make an Iterator on values from function calls

Tags: scala, iterator

Let there is a function `foo(): Int`. For example, each call `foo()` returns different values. Just to illustrate:

```
var i: Int = 0

def foo(): Int = {
    i += 1
    i
}
```

I would like to iterate through these values. Actually, I would like to construct an `Iterator` `it` so that each call `it.next()` computed by `foo()` called repeatedly. How it can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I always say, the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator$.html) is your friend.

```
Iterator.continually(foo())
```

Answer (score 3):

Luis's answer is better, but here's another way to do it:

```
new Iterator[Int] {
  override def hasNext: Boolean = true
  override def next: Int = foo()
}
```